# Read Mail Attchments in appengine using Java

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I am using App Engine application  to receive emails to a specific list of  email address ending with @my-app-id.appspotmail.com will be sent to your application.

```
    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
       BodyPart bp = multiPart.getBodyPart(0);
       log.info("count is "+multiPart.getCount());

       String attachFiles = "";
       String messageContent = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {

           MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
           if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
               // this part is attachment
               String fileName = part.getFileName();
               log.info("file name is "+fileName);

           } else {
               // this part may be the message content
               messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
           } 
       }
```

I want to store the File inside a Blob store but i did not find an API  for it, It is going inside the IF loop and am able to get the attachment file name. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can read all the data inside the attachment part using the [MimeBodyPart.getInputStream](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#getInputStream--) method, but you'll need to read the data yourself and create the Blob.